# Can ASP .NET MVC help me converting IDs to models in my action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Consider an HTML form built in the following way:

```
        <select name="schoolType">
            @foreach (SchoolType schoolType in Model.SchoolTypes)
            {
                <option value="@schoolType.Id">@schoolType.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
```

Now, SchoolType is a model class. It's designed in my EDMX for Entity Framework.

In the above scenario, right now, my action method looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult CreateSchool(int schoolType)
    {
        ...
        SchoolType myType = container.SchoolTypeSet.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == schoolType);
        ...
    }
```

Would it be possible to program some kind of helper so that MVC would automatically know to convert the integer into a Model class with that ID, like the following action method signature?

```
    public ActionResult CreateSchool(SchoolType schoolType)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ModelBinder to accomplish this:

```
public ActionResult CreateSchool([ModelBinder(typeof(SchoolTypeBinder))] SchoolType schoolType)
{
    ...
}
```

Where your Model Binder looks like:

```
public class SchoolTypeBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        SchoolType output = null;

        int id;
        ValueProviderResult parameter = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("id");
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            id = (int)parameter.ConvertTo(typeof(int));
            output = container.SchoolTypeSet.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

You can also associate binders with types globally at startup:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(SchoolType), new SchoolTypeBinder());
}
```

resulting in the nice, clean action you requested:

```
public ActionResult CreateSchool(SchoolType schoolType)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually wrap it in some abstraction called DataSource that exposes current value and current id.
As far as primary keys are often of the same type all over solution (int, Guid) you can register model binder for datasource.
You can use some kind of helper like below to output it to your view:

```
    public static SelectList ToSelectList<T, T1>(this DataSource<T, T1> dataSource)
    {
        return dataSource == null
            ? new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<string>()) 
            : new SelectList(dataSource, "Key", "Value", dataSource.CurrentValue);
    }
```

And in your editor template you can use just
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model, Model.ToSelectList())